# video subtitles loading twice with onclick jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I hope someone could give me a solution to my problem.

I have a web page that plays a video. underneath the video I have Four Buttons
that when click changes to another video. each video will have subtitles with a .vtt file.

now the problem I'm having is each time i click the other button to play a different video the previous videos' subtitle load to the current video, when clicking back to the first video the subtitles begin to load on top of each other and stack up filing the screen. 
so when clicking thru the buttons to view the other videos, all the subtitles from the other videos stack up on top of each other.
please help:)

this is the html code

```
    <video id="videoclip" class=" embed-responsive-item animated bounceIn" 
    width="760" height="415" controls>
    <source id="mp4video" src="../vid/video1.mp4">
    <track id="subtitle" src="../vid/subtitles/video1sub.vtt" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" 
    label="English">
    </video>
```

and the javascrip/jquery

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
            //HTML5 video object
            var detailedVidObj = "#videoclip";


            //Reload the video object and automatically play it
            function videoReloader(){
                $(detailedVidObj)[0].load();
                $(detailedVidObj)[0].play();

            }

            $("#video1").click(function(){
                $("#mp4video").attr("src", "../vid/video1.mp4");
                $("#subtitle").attr("src", "../vid/subtitles/video1sub.vtt");
                videoReloader();
            });
            $("#video2").click(function(){
                $("#mp4video").attr("src", "../vid/video2.mp4");
                $("#subtitle").attr("src", "../vid/subtitles/video2sub.vtt");
                videoReloader();
            });
            $("#video3").click(function(){
                $("#mp4video").attr("src", "../vid/video3.mp4");
                $("#subtitle").attr("src", "../vid/subtitles/video3sub.vtt");
                videoReloader();
            });
            $("#video4").click(function(){
                $("#mp4video").attr("src", "../vid/video4.mp4");
                $("#subtitle").attr("src", "../vid/subtitles/video4sub.vtt");
                videoReloader();
            });
        });
```

and this is the html for the buttons

```
<button class="button btn btn-primary" id="video1">video One</button>
    <button class="button btn btn-primary" id="video2">Video Two</button>
    <button class="button btn btn-primary" id="video3">Video Three</button>
    <button class="button btn btn-primary" id="video4">Video Four</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that when you load a new subtitle file, the old one is not replaced and keeps playing. In this case, removing the initial subtitle element and creating a new one with the new subtitle file should work:

```
 $("#video1").click(function(){
            $("#mp4video").attr("src", "../vid/video1.mp4");
            $("#subtitle").remove();
            $("#videoclip").append("<track id='subtitle' src='../vid/subtitles/video1sub.vtt' kind='subtitles' srclang='en' 
             label='English'>");
            videoReloader();
        });
 $("#video2").click(function(){
            $("#mp4video").attr("src", "../vid/video2.mp4");
            $("#subtitle").remove();
            $("#videoclip").append("<track id='subtitle' src='../vid/subtitles/video2sub.vtt' kind='subtitles' srclang='en' 
             label='English'>");
            videoReloader();
        });
 $("#video3").click(function(){
            $("#mp4video").attr("src", "../vid/video3.mp4");
            $("#subtitle").remove();
            $("#videoclip").append("<track id='subtitle' src='../vid/subtitles/video3sub.vtt' kind='subtitles' srclang='en' 
             label='English'>");
            videoReloader();
        });
 $("#video4").click(function(){
            $("#mp4video").attr("src", "../vid/video4.mp4");
            $("#subtitle").remove();
            $("#videoclip").append("<track id='subtitle' src='../vid/subtitles/video4sub.vtt' kind='subtitles' srclang='en' 
             label='English'>");
            videoReloader();
        });
```